# Efficient way to pass Bitmap into registered COM component

Tags: c#, .net, com, regasm

I have registered COM Class and interface written in .NET 2.0 . Now i am looking for a way to pass Bitmap object from WindowsForms .Net 4.5 application into COM component.

When i try to do this code:

```
 Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid);
 source = (IBaseFilter) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        public void SetBitmap(Bitmap input)
        {
 IImageSourceFilter advSource = (IImageSourceFilter)source;
 advSource.SetBitmapObj(input);
        }
```

I get next exception

```
    System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
  Source=DShow
  StackTrace:
   at RTSPTestAPP.Camera.BMPtoCam.IImageSourceFilter.SetBitmapObj(Object inp)
   at RTSPTestAPP.Camera.BMPtoCam.SetBitmap(Bitmap input) in C:\Users\...\BMPtoCam.cs:line 43
```

Passing it as byte array is not efficient and locates a lot CPU resources (and i am sending alot bitmaps from decoded videostream).

Comment: This fails in a [ComVisible] .NET library, it is not a Bitmap object anymore.  You make it efficient by *not* using COM to call a .NET library method, add a reference to the assembly instead.  In general do strongly avoid using DirectShow, it was deprecated 12 years ago, for a good reason.

Comment: @HansPassant i don`t have any other alternatives for creating virtual webcam with minimum c++ code

Comment: You are not using C++ code yet, it can't create a Bitmap object either.  Testing code you can never run in the final project can't be very useful.  "Don't have" is not the same thing as "don't know".  You don't need DS to use .NET code, a [ComVisible] assembly is just as usable as DS in a C++ program.  Well, more.  Use the #import directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way: i just develop COM component with same .net as program which will use it. Then on `Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid);` i'll get not raw type (System.__ComObject), instead i`ll get correct interface, with correct methods. And i just pass bitmap as argument. Its important too add reference to this assembly too.